# Что я делаю не так при передаче файла через объект Formdata AJAX?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Плохо понимаю сам принцип работы этих методов, поэто взяяв [готовое решение отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax/10899796#10899796) не получил ровным счётом никакого результа — `print_r($_POST);` и `print_r($_FILES);` путстые.

Разжуйте, пожалуйста

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="title">Название</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
  <label for="description">Описание</label>
  <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea>

  <label for="file" class="mt-5">Добавьте изображения</label>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

  <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" id="errorBlock"></div>

  <button type="button" id="send_prjct" class="btn btn-dark mt-3">Добавить</button>
</form>

<script>
$("form#data").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();    
      var formData = new FormData(this);

   
   $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/add_project.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: FormData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
     if (data == 'Готово'){
      $('#send_prjct').text('Выполнено');
      $('#errorBlock').hide();
     } else {
      $('#errorBlock').show();
      $('#errorBlock').text(data);
     }
    }  
   });
  });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий вариант:

[image: Результат:]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И с выводом "Готово":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="title">Название</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control"><br>
  <label for="description">Описание</label>
  <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea><br>

  <label for="file" class="mt-5">Добавьте изображения</label>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>

  <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" id="errorBlock"></div><br>

  <button type="submit" id="send_prjct" class="btn btn-dark mt-3">Добавить</button>
</form>

<script>
$("#data").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'files.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 'Готово'){
                        $('#send_prjct').text('Выполнено');
                        $('#errorBlock').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#errorBlock').show();
                        $('#errorBlock').text(data);
                    }
                }       
            });
        });     
    </script>
```

`files.php` - куда отправлял

1 вариант с `print_r`

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); 
print_r($_FILES);
//echo 'Готово';
?>
```

Вариант с "Готово":

```
<?php
//print_r($_POST); 
//print_r($_FILES);
echo 'Готово';
?>
```

*UPD по комменту:

Все стандартно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`files.php`:

```
<?php
//print_r($_POST);
//echo '||||||||||';
//print_r($_FILES);

echo 'Title: '.$_POST['title'].' | ';
echo 'Description: '.$_POST['description'].' | ';
echo 'fileToUpload_name: '.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'].' | ';
echo 'fileToUpload_tmp_name: '.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'].' | ';
echo 'fileToUpload_size: '.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'].' | ';
echo 'fileToUpload_error: '.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'].' | ';
echo 'fileToUpload_type: '.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'].' | ';

//echo 'Готово';
?>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, а в чем ошибка-то была?

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов submit не прикручен, data не FormData в отсыле, а formData, не form#data, а form #data и проще #data и... вроде и все

Comment: @Coder, а как получать переменные? Я пробовал 
$title = $_POST['title'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];
 $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];

 $fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
 $fileTmpName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
 $fileSize = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
 $fileError = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];
 $fileType = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
Но получаю ошибку сервера 500

Comment: @Nonono - добавил в ответ. Больше не подскажешь - 500 может быть от неправильного htaccess до многого и многого.